# Unexpected undefined Value in JS Script

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm

I am solving [this](https://leetcode.com/problems/happy-number/) problem. I want to solve it in JS.

I have a function in JS to solve this (**is_Happy**), all my code is given bellow-

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("fname");
    n = Number(x.value);
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=
                                   is_Happy(n);
}

function is_Happy(n)
{
    if(n<10)
    {
        if(n==1 || n==7)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    else
    {
        is_Happy( calculate_value( get_digit(n) ) );
    }
}

function get_digit(number)
{
    var output = [];
    var sNumber = number.toString();

    for (var i = 0, len = sNumber.length; i < len; i += 1) {
        output.push(+sNumber.charAt(i));
    }
    return output;
}

function calculate_value(num_array)
{
    var sum=0;
    var i=0;
    while(num_array.length>i)
    {
        number = Number(num_array[i]);
        if(number>0)
            sum+=num_array[i]*num_array[i];
        i++;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

```html
<p id = "output">character to upper case.</p>
Enter your name: <input type="text" id="fname" onkeyup="myFunction()">
```

The problem is I should have find something (true/false) if I give input any number, but I am getting undefined if I input any number greater than 9 (10 or above).

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Why do you think it should return anything other than `undefined`?

Comment: Please try giving input 10 or 11 or anything in the code snippets, and please if u don't understand, don't underrate the question so that the answer can't be found.

Comment: I understand what your problem is and how to solve it. You don’t return anything in the `else` branch. Why do you think it should return `true` or `false`?

Comment: your  is_Happy(n) is return undefined.

Comment: You want to achieve like all text should be uppercase or only first latter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you doesn't return anything in function else part.
return `is_Happy`

```
return is_Happy( calculate_value( get_digit(n) ) );
```

Following working code.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("fname");
    n = Number(x.value);
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=
                                   is_Happy(n);
}

function is_Happy(n)
{
    if(n<10)
    {
        if(n==1 || n==7)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    else
    {
      
      return is_Happy( calculate_value( get_digit(n) ) );
      
    }
}

function get_digit(number)
{
    var output = [];
    var sNumber = number.toString();

    for (var i = 0, len = sNumber.length; i < len; i += 1) {
        output.push(+sNumber.charAt(i));
    }
    return output;
}

function calculate_value(num_array)
{
    var sum=0;
    var i=0;
    while(num_array.length>i)
    {
        number = Number(num_array[i]);
        if(number>0)
            sum+=num_array[i]*num_array[i];
        i++;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id = "output">character to upper case.</p>
Enter your name: <input type="text" id="fname" onkeyup="myFunction()">



</body>
</html>
```